# Nested Meta Query with post_where and multiple relation keys

Tags: mysql, custom-post-type, wordpress

I'm trying to add a`WP_Query` with 
`post_where` filter and `WP_META_QUERY` to a wordpress main query:

```
function example_range_m2( $where ) {

$min_price = doubleval($_GET['min-price']);
$max_price = doubleval($_GET['max-price']);

    $query_args = array( 'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'PREFIX_min_property_price_m2',
            'value' => array($min_price, $max_price),
            'type' => 'NUMERIC',
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'PREFIX_max_property_price_m2',
            'value' => array($max_price, $min_price),
            'type' => 'NUMERIC',
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
        ),
    ) );

    $query_args2 = array('meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'PREFIX_min_property_price_m2',
            'value' => $min_price,
            'compare' => '<=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'PREFIX_max_property_price_m2',
            'value' => $max_price,
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        ),
    ));

$meta_query = new WP_Meta_Query();
$meta_query->parse_query_vars( $query_args );
$mq_sql = $meta_query->get_sql(
    'post',
    $wpdb->posts,
    'ID',
    null
);

$tmp_one = str_replace('mt1', 'example_postmeta', $mq_sql['where']) . ' ';

echo $tmp_one;
$meta_query = new WP_Meta_Query();
$meta_query->parse_query_vars( $query_args2 );
$mq_sql = $meta_query->get_sql(
    'post',
    $wpdb->posts,
    'ID',
    null
);
$tmp_two = str_replace('mt1', 'example_postmeta', $mq_sql['where']) . ' ';
$where .=  $tmp_one . ' OR ' . $tmp_two;

return $where;
}
```

The first `query_arg`s have to determine whether one of the `custom_meta_field` value are between the given range. 
The secound `query_arg`s have to determine whether values in the database make a range that contains given range.

I need to make wordpress to query database:

```
SELECT post_meta WHERE 
(meta_value1 BETWEEN min MAX max) OR (meta_value2 BETWEEN min AND max) 
OR (meta_value1 <= min AND meta_value2 >= max)
```

`var_dump` of main wordpress query gives me following request:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS example_posts.id
FROM   example_posts
INNER JOIN example_postmeta
ON ( example_posts.id = example_postmeta.post_id )
WHERE
   1 = 1
   AND example_posts.post_type = 'property'
   AND (
         example_posts.post_status = 'publish'
         OR
         example_posts.post_status = 'private'
       )
   AND ( example_postmeta.meta_key = 'PREFIX_min_property_price_m2' )
   AND (
         (
           example_postmeta.meta_key = 'PREFIX_min_property_price_m2'
           AND
           Cast(example_postmeta.meta_value AS signed) BETWEEN '1000' AND '9000'
         )
         OR
         (
           example_postmeta.meta_key = 'PREFIX_max_property_price_m2'
           AND
           Cast(example_postmeta.meta_value AS signed) BETWEEN '9000' AND '1000'
         )
       )
   OR
   And (
         (
           example_postmeta.meta_key = 'PREFIX_min_property_price_m2'
           AND
           Cast(example_postmeta.meta_value AS signed) <= '1000'
         )
         AND
         (
           example_postmeta.meta_key = 'PREFIX_max_property_price_m2'
           AND Cast(example_postmeta.meta_value AS signed) >= '9000'
         )
       )
GROUP  BY example_posts.id
ORDER  BY example_postmeta.meta_value + 0 ASC
LIMIT  0, 4
```

I need this to work with main `WP_Query` in order to maintain WP and template logic.
I have one post that should work with request and it just doesn't. 
I'm a SQL Noob if that is not obvious ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. After a strong brainstorming session with myself and a piece of paper and pen I understood that I can rephrase my query / 'problem' with totally different conditions. 
I was trying write a query that will return all the objects with a range of values that meet a  range. I decided that I will work on maximum and minimum values in a different way, so I came up with meta query that could be used in standard `WP_QUERY`:

```
 /* Logic for Min and Max Price Parameters */
    if( isset($_GET['min-price']) && ($_GET['min-price'] != 'any') && isset($_GET['max-price']) && ($_GET['max-price'] != 'any') ){
        $min_price = doubleval($_GET['min-price']);
        $max_price = doubleval($_GET['max-price']);
        if( $min_price >= 0 && $max_price > $min_price ){

            $meta_query[] = array(
                'key' => 'EXAMPLE_max_property_price_m2',
                'value' => $min_price,
                'type' => 'NUMERIC',
                'compare' => '>='
            );

            $meta_query[] = array(
                'key' => 'EXAMPLE_min_property_price_m2',
                'value' => $max_price,
                'type' => 'NUMERIC',
                'compare' => '<='
            );

        }
    }elseif( isset($_GET['min-price']) && ($_GET['min-price'] != 'any') ){
        $min_price = doubleval($_GET['min-price']);
        if( $min_price > 0 ){
            $meta_query[] = array(
                'key' => 'EXAMPLE_max_property_price_m2',
                'value' => $min_price,
                'type' => 'NUMERIC',
                'compare' => '>='
            );
        }
    }elseif( isset($_GET['max-price']) && ($_GET['max-price'] != 'any') ){
        $max_price = doubleval($_GET['max-price']);
        if( $max_price > 0 ){
            $meta_query[] = array(
                'key' => 'EXAMPLE_min_property_price_m2',
                'value' => $max_price,
                'type' => 'NUMERIC',
                'compare' => '<='
            );
        }
    }
```

This allowed me to cover all the objects I while comparing ranges.